# A mySQL query to check one option, and if not true, another option?

Tags: mysql

I am very new at mySQL.

I am doing a lookup of certain records from a table and the requirements have now changed. At first the query would pull the name of the person who was marked as the captain on the job plus a few other conditions. Now my boss wants me to pull the transcriber on the job if there is no captain.  How can I do this in mySQL?

My code is:

```
$Q = $this->read_db->query('
        select DISTINCT j.id, j.reference, max(ja.FinalDue) as FinalDue, j.clientdue, j.pagecount, t.name, ja.iscaptain
            from `job` j 
            join `jobattachment` a on a.`jobid` = j.`id`
            join `jobassignment` ja on a.`jobid` = ja.`jobid`
            join `transcriber` t on ja.`transcriberid` = t.`id`
            where ja.`iscaptain` = 1 
            and ja.`deleted` != 1
            and (a.`editing` = 2 or a.`editing` = 3)
            and a.`redline` != 0
            and j.`complete` = 0
            group by j.id');
    return $Q->result_array();
```

How can I make the query find the captain, and only if there is no captain, find the person whose ID is in the redline field?  The jobattachment table has multiple records for each job and if the attachment is marked as a redline, the transcriber's ID would be in that field, otherwise it would be empty.

I tried changing the query by adding an or, but I don't want the captain or the transcriber, only the transcriber if there is no captain.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Your existing query is flawed. Consequently, the question proceeds on a false premise. See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Can you explain why it is flawed? As I said, I'm new to mySQL so any help would be much appreciated.  I am starting to think that I should remove the `ja.iscaptain = 1` clause and then filter all the results afterwards.

Comment: Specifically, your query returns an indeterminate result for t.name (in the event that there could be more than 1 transcriber). There may be other, similar flaws, but without knowing your schema, I couldn't say. Also, you almost never see DISTINCT and GROUP BY together in the same level of a query.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I am reworking the query and have removed DISTINCT and GROUP BY for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I played around with this a lot and this is the solution I have come up with.  Thank you to everyone that responded.

```
public function getRedlinesNotCompleted() {
    $Q = $this->read_db->query('
        select j.id, j.reference, max(ja.FinalDue) as FinalDue, j.clientdue, j.pagecount, t.name, max(ja.iscaptain) as iscaptain
            from `job` j
            join `jobattachment` a on a.`jobid` = j.`id`
            join `jobassignment` ja on a.`jobid` = ja.`jobid`
            join `transcriber` t on ja.`transcriberid` = t.`id`
            where ja.`deleted` != 1
            and (a.`editing` = 2 or a.`editing` = 3)
            and a.`redline` != 0
            and j.`complete` = 0
            group by j.id');
    return $Q->result_array();
}

public function getCaptainNameForRedlineJobsNotCompleted($jobid) {
    $Q = $this->read_db->query('
    SELECT t.name, max(j.iscaptain) as iscaptain 
    FROM jobassignment j 
    JOIN transcriber t ON t.id = j.transcriberid
    WHERE j.jobid = ' . $jobid . ' AND j.iscaptain = 1');
    return $Q->row()->name;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
select DISTINCT j.id, j.reference, max(ja.FinalDue) as FinalDue, j.clientdue, j.pagecount, case when ja.iscaptain then t.name else (select name from t where id = a.redline) end , ja.iscaptain
        from `job` j 
        join `jobattachment` a on a.`jobid` = j.`id`
        join `jobassignment` ja on a.`jobid` = ja.`jobid`
        join `transcriber` t on ja.`transcriberid` = t.`id`
        where 
        and ja.`deleted` != 1
        and (a.`editing` = 2 or a.`editing` = 3)
        and a.`redline` != 0
        and j.`complete` = 0
        group by j.id'
```

Explanation:
First remove the `ja.iscaptain = 1` part from the where clause so you can get all the people that also not captains.

Second, the `t.name` is changed according to the person if he is a captain or not, so instead of returning it hardcoded, you should check if its a captain then its name is `t.name`, else get the name from transcriber table by `a.redline` id.

I hope that I understood it correctly and it helps :)

Comment: Thank you for your response. I will give it a try.

Comment: Ameen, thank you for the response, but that didn't accomplish what I needed. I need to get the captain's name from the ID, but if there is no captain, I need to insert the transcriber's name. I want the program to check for a captain, and failing that, find the transcriber and pass their name in.

Comment: The only thing that is different is the name that would be passed through.

Comment: The question is confusing, can you explain where the captain's name and the transcriber's are located ? and where are their id's ?

Comment: The jobattachment table contains a field called redline. When a redline is uploaded for someone, their id is put into the redline field on the row that lists the attachment. I need to call the transcriber table to look up the id and find the name of the transcriber.  In the jobassignment table, it lists all the people working on the job and there is a field, iscaptain, which is 1 if the person is the captain for the job. To find the captain, I would need to see if iscaptain = 1, and if so, get the transcriberid field value and, again, look the name up in the transcriber table.

Comment: If there is no one in the jobassignment table that is marked as iscaptain, I would need to get the id (and name) of the person whose id is in the redline field and display that instead.